# How can I set this .map() to only output 5 items and add new items at the top of the list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My app currently displays a list of times whenever a button is held down and a 'Done!' button is pressed. The list continues on off the screen so I want to add a new time to the top of the list and limit the list to 5 items only.

I've tried .unshift and .pop but because the list is stored in state I'm not supposed to mutate the state! So I decided that I could do this in the render by configuring what the .map is showing.

Here's the submit button function:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    scoreArray: state.scoreArray.concat(ms(state.time,{verbose: true})),
    time:0,
    submit:true
  })
);
```

Here is the render:

```
<Button onPress={this.onSubmit} title="Done!"/>
  {this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item, i) {
    return <Text key={i}>{item}</Text>
  })}
```

Could I put a limitation of 5 on this .map and make it add the latest time to the top of the list?

Comment: Look into `.filter` not `.map` More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: `this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item, i) {
    return (i < 5) ?<Text key={i}>{item}</Text> : null
  }).filter(x=>x)`

Comment: Can you tell me what I could put for .filter(x => x)? 
My array is called sampleInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting new element on top, and not to mutate original one you can use spread oprator, like

```
this.setState((state) => ({
    scoreArray: [newElement, ...state.scoreArray]
    time:0,
    submit:true
  })
```

For  limitation of 5, update your code with

```
this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item, i) {
  return (i < 5) ?<Text key={i}>{item}</Text> : null 
}).filter(x=>x)
```

Comment: This isn't working. The .map you provided is creating scores exponentially.

Comment: Is the x=>x placeholders for me to fill in? I've read the docs for .filter but not seen anything like that before.

Comment: `x=>x` removes the falsy values

Comment: Can you explain why I'm getting multiple scores listing? It's a combination of the spread operator and the .map .filter you provided.